# Form validation works only on the active tab

Tags: validation, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

**My issue**

A .Net Core form feeded with taghelpers. The form has a Bootstrap 4 validation.
The form has a Tab1 and a Tab2 tab.

I have a mandatory input file in each form that should be validated.

When I validate, only the input of the active tab is validated

**What I did**

This is the form code:

```
@model DataModel

@using WebApplication6.Controllers

<form asp-action="ContactForm" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="container tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <label for="FirstName">Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="FirstName" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="container tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            <label for="LastName">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="LastName" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

My data model is:

```
public class DataModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**What I am looking for**

What should I change in order to LastName and FirstName validates at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery.validation, it only validates visible controls.

Since the inactive tab is hidden when you submit the form, you need to configure the `$.validator` to validate hidden elements (which are not validated by default).

Add below code to your `@section Scripts`

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
    <script>
        $.validator.setDefaults({ 
            ignore: [] 
        });
    </script>

}
```

Note: do not add the above inside $(document).ready()